# Finding location of character in input2 from input1

Tags: c++, arrays, string

**Important note:** *string (C++ object)* and any other library such as *array* or *vectors* that could store unlimited characters cannot be used.

For my question:
We are given **input 1**, which is a sentence of unlimited characters. eg. Life is Beautiful.

**Input 2**: character who's location we have to find using the reference point (the middle character in input 1 after it is sorted and repeating characters are deleted) taken as zero. eg. fee.

```
An example:
Input 1: Life is beautiful
Input 2: see

Output: 2, -2, -2
```

**Explanation:** So firstly, we remove any spaces from input 1 and make all lowercase, then sort it in ascending order after which we find the reference letter (For above example, it's 'i'). We remove the repeating characters and then finally, put positions to character in input 1.

```
Example 2
Input 1: abcde
Input 2: aad

Output: -2, -2, 1
```

If the input 2 contains reference point, then the code returns zero.
Eg.

```
An example:
Input 1: abcde
Input 2: cab

Output: 0
```

The input1 is always odd and input2 is always 10 character max.

The problem I have is that I am not sure how to store these inputs without using strings, array etc. And even if I know how to store them, I cannot compare the inputs like input1[1] = input2[1] because we cannot use arrays/strings.

*Is list an useful option with regards to important note?*

I have mostly done it with the use of array but not sure how to approach it without the array. I tried to loop a character but it only stores the first character.

My practice code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char input1;

    for(int i =0; i < 3; i++ ) //for chacking whether the loops work or not.

    {
        cin >> input1;

    }

    cout<< input1;

    char input2;

}
```

Please add any relevant tags.
I hope all the edits help.

Comment: Is there any reason for the seemingly absurd restriction to not use arrays/vectors? You question says that input1 can have unlimited size. You need some sort of container to store and manipulate it.

Comment: I am not really sure myself. I re-checked with my teacher and he said that you cannot use vectors, array or string.

Comment: @super The main problem for me is also to how to store the data. I thought of using list but not sure whether it is limited library or not.

Comment: A `std::list` would get the job done. If your allowed to use that. If not you could write your own double-linked list and use it. There are tons of examples of how to write/use them here on SO and other places.

Comment: This reminds me to [Stop Teaching C - Kate Gregory](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2015/blob/master/Presentations/Stop%20Teaching%20C/Stop%20Teaching%20C%20-%20Kate%20Gregory%20-%20CppCon%202015.pptx). ;-) A list could be an option. Another option could be a self-written vector. May be, your teacher had a certain intention what he/she actually intends to teach. In the latter case, you might use an array with fixed size as temp. storage (not `std::array` - it's part of language - no library required) and `new[]` to (re-)allocate persistent storage on heap and copy the contents of temp. buffer.

Comment: @UtsoRoy time to write your own dynamic array class.

Comment: What is the goal? It will be easy to use the C library to have the job done *as it would be in C language*. Or the goal may be to use true C++ io and iterators but build your own classes. Without knowing that I cannot propose a way...

Comment: @SergeBallesta we are allowed to use any library except the ones that allow for unlimited character storage.

Comment: @Scheff I cannot use the array with fixed temporary because that's the approach i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KushanMehta proposed a C-ish solution. A more C++ one would be to implement a class wrapping a dynamic array of *elements*. In C++ it could be:

```
template <class T> 
class MyArr {
protected:
    T *arr;             // a pointer to the dynamic array
    size_t len;         // the used length
    size_t capacity;    // the allocated capacity
    ...
```

As it contains a pointer to dynamic array, you cannot rely on default members, and should implement copy and move constructor and assignation operator and a destructor.

In order to be able to use all the goodies of C++ algorithm library, you should declare [c]begin() and [c]end() functions pointing to beginning of array and one past last element.

```
const T* cbegin() const {
    return arr;
}
const T* cend() const {
    return arr + len;
}
```

Then you need a subclass for characters implementing some methods to convert all characters to lower case and remove spaces, sort the array and remove duplicates. You should write io specializations for operator `<<` and `>>` to be able to input strings from stdin and output them

The `MyArr` class can be used directly to store the resul value: just derive a specialization for `int` elements and implement the required specifications.

That may not be really easy, but you will learn C++ that way (not C)

Comment: my complier shows this error:
error: 'T' does not name a type
 const T* cbegin() const {

Answer (score 0):

You could do one thing to store the sentences by the use of dynamic memory for each character (sounds absurd but it is the only possible thing without actually worrying about the size of the input)

Meaning you take input till the user wants, in the meanwhile you can use malloc and realloc() for each new character, incrementing the size of your pointer to char for every new character.
(This is probably the way vector etc works on the naive level - not sure of this though)

Code snippet for the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char temp;

    char *sentence = (char*) malloc(2*sizeof(char));

    int counter = 0;

    while( cin>>temp ){



        sentence[counter++] = temp;

        sentence = (char*) realloc(sentence, (counter+2)*sizeof(char));

    }

    sentence[counter] = '\0';

    cout<<"The sentence is"<<endl<<strlen(sentence)<<endl<<sentence;


}
```